# How to get list to sort by alphabetically by last name but keep first name first in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, es6-promise

I'm playing around with an API that returns back a list of names. I have the list displaying but I need it to sort alphabetically by the last name but keep the first name first. Here is the code that works:

```
const url = 'https://swapi.co/api/species/1/';
   function fetchData(url) {
  return fetch(url).then((resp) => resp.json());
}

  function constructTableRow(data) {
    const row = document.createElement('tr');
    const { name, height, mass, hair_color } = data;
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', name))
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', height))
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', mass))
    row.appendChild(constructElement('td', hair_color))
    return row;
  }

  const swTable = document.getElementById('sw-table').getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
     fetchData(url).then(data =>
     data.people.forEach(personUrl =>
     fetchData(personUrl).then(result => {
     result.name.sort()
     const row = constructTableRow(result);
     swTable.appendChild(row);
   })
  )
);
```

When I add `result.name.sort()` to the last block of code, it breaks and says:

`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: result.name.sort is not a function
    at fetchData.then.result`

what's missing here?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming name contains two space separated strings.

This is the minimal code I can think of, for helping you in solving your case.

```
function fetchData(test)
{
    return {"name": test};
}


data = {people:["foo deep", "flying bar", "come and"]};
list = [];
data.people.forEach(personUrl =>{
    list.push(fetchData(personUrl));
});
list.sort(function(a, b) {
    var a_last_name = a.name.split(" ")[1];
    var b_last_name = b.name.split(" ")[1];
    if(a_last_name < b_last_name)
        return -1;
    else if (a_last_name == b_last_name)
        return 0;
    return 1;
});
```

Comment: Thanks the names actually are in the JSON as name: "Luke Skywalker"

Comment: @MikeL5799, yes I have written it assuming 2 word names, you can modify it accordingly, if you need something else.

Comment: so when I add this code inside of` fetchData(url).then(data =>` it doesn't work. should this be after that instead?

Comment: I have updated it for more clarity. Can you print the result before sorting it. This will help in understanding the problem better.

Comment: thanks. That actually makes an error:`result.sort is not a function` the joys of coding lol

Comment: can you please print the `result` before calling `sort`, I'm sure, its not an array, if you are getting the above mentioned error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168341/discussion-between-harman786-and-mikel5799).

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to get sort by alphabetically by the last name

```
var sortedPeople= data.people.sort(function(a, b){
   if(a.lastNameKey < b.lastNameKey) return -1;
   if(a.lastNameKey > b.lastNameKey) return 1;
   return 0;
});

sortedPeople.forEach(function(element) {
     const row = constructTableRow(result);
     swTable.appendChild(row);
});
```